# How to pass parameter to Android Alarm Manager's callback function Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alarmmanager

Android Alarm Manager triggers once its time is reached at the moment. When that means it triggers also its callback function to handle some jobs according to the structure. However, when sending message or parameters to use it on the callback function to do some tasks, it is unclear that how I can set a specific alarm with a certain value on Alarm Manager Function.

```
        await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
          const Duration(seconds: 5),
          // Ensure we have a unique alarm ID.
          Random().nextInt(pow(2, 31)),
          callback,
          exact: true,
          wakeup: true,
        );
```

That call function is below here. But it can't get passed variable from its parent functions.

```
  // The callback for our alarm
  static Future<void> callback() async {
    print('Alarm fired!');

    // Get the previous cached count and increment it.
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int currentCount = prefs.getInt(countKey);
    await prefs.setInt(countKey, currentCount + 1);

    // This will be null if we're running in the background.
    uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    uiSendPort?.send(null);
  }
```

My main purpose is to use Android Alarm Manager as reminder application.

Comment: I've solved it with using sqflite by saving index and other data such as timestamp, message, id, and other stuff. Then after Alarm is triggered, you'll have an index and you can fetch data from SQFLITE database using the index.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use alarmId in your callback funtion just by using formal parameters not actual and the use the variable to get the particular data.

```
// The callback for our alarm
static Future<void> callback(int alarmId) async {
print('Alarm fired! : ' + alarmId);

// Get the previous cached count and increment it.
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int currentCount = prefs.getInt(countKey);
await prefs.setInt(countKey, currentCount + 1);

// This will be null if we're running in the background.
uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
uiSendPort?.send(null);
}
```

Additionally you should use sqflite database which is a relational local Database which stores you reminder info in local disk of mobile and in future you can get it by using this unique alarmId (if you insert it in your table)

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

This docs will help you to perform the basic CRUD operation with sqflite.

Hopefully it will help you.